# Surjectivity of a function that maps three subsets to their union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $E$ be a set and $A,B,C$ three subsets of $E$.
Consider the function
$$f:\mathcal{P}(A)\times \mathcal{P}(B)\times \mathcal{P}(C)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(E);\; (X,Y,Z)\mapsto X\cup Y\cup Z$$

I want to show that if $f$ is surjective then $E\subset A\cup B\cup C$.

Let $x\in E$ then the singleton $\{x\}\in \mathcal{P}(E)$ and by surjectivity there exists 
$(X,Y,Z) \in \mathcal{P}(A)\times \mathcal{P}(B)\times \mathcal{P}(C)$ such that $  X\cup Y\cup Z=\{x\}$
Hence $X=\{x\}$ or  $Y=\{x\}$ or  $Z=\{x\}$ so $\{x\}\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ or $\{x\}\in \mathcal{P}(B)$ or $\{x\}\in \mathcal{P}(C)$ hence $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ or $x\in C$ so $x\in A\cup B\cup C$.
Is this correct? and is there any other simpler way to do this? thank you for your help!!

Comment: Hint: For $M\subset E$ consider the sets $M\cap A$, $M\cap B$ and $M\cap C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but here is a simpler argument:

If $f$ is surjective, then $f^{-1}(E)$ is non-empty, so there are $A'\subseteq A,B'\subseteq B,C'\subseteq C$ such that their union is equal to $E$. In particular $A\cup B\cup C=E$ as well.

Comment: yes much simpler, thank you Asaf!!

Comment: You're welcome. You can also show it is injective if and only if the three sets are disjoint.

Comment: Yes I already did that. Thanks again !!